# How to catch DOMException in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-orientation, domexception

I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: lockOrientation() is not available on this device.
  code: 9
  message: "lockOrientation() is not available on this device."
  name: "NotSupportedError"
```

when I run the following code in Chrome:

```js
try {
  screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
} catch (error) {
  // whatever
}
```

The fact that the error is being thrown is expected, since Desktop Chrome doesn't support orientation locking. I'd like to catch the error so it doesn't litter the console, but wrapping it in a `try...catch` block doesn't seem to work.

Why can't I catch it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Synchronous `try/catch` does not work here, because `screen.orientation.lock('portrait');` actually returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is throwing the error. This part of the error shows the exception is thrown in the promise.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: lockOrientation() is not available on this device.

To handle the exception, you can attach a `catch` callback.

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait').catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Alternately in an async function, you can try/catch an await.

```
try {
    await screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Thats just what I needed, thanks! Since other implementations return true/false and Chrome returns a promise, I wrote up a gist on how to combine the various implementations into one function. https://gist.github.com/jacksenechal/67315945593d452407ff