# Catch not triggering when there is an error (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, web, error-handling

here is the code:

```
        try{
            document.getElementById("audioplayer").play()

        }
        catch {
            window.location.href = "https://vibify.fepzz.repl.co/get-song-redirect_name_download=" +  document.getElementById("error-catcher-link").innerHTML 
        }
```

This is inside a function that gets called on load and everytime it gets called i get an error in the `try` but the catch block doesnt `catch`it for some reason.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: The error im  getting is  the audio element has no support audio sources

Comment: So why is it not triggering ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question and paste the _full_ error message? There’s one of two explanations: either it’s not a JavaScript error, but a network error, which cannot be caught, or it says “Uncaught (in promise)” which means that the error doesn’t originate from this execution context. The link below may be useful. `.play` returns a promise which has a `.catch` method; so try `.play().catch(() => window.location.href =`…`)`.

Comment: Very related to (maybe even a duplicate of?) [How to catch DOMException in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509619/how-to-catch-domexception-in-chrome)

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes i used `.play().catch()` and it worked thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, i just had to use

```
.play().catch(() => {
console.log("error playing")
})
```

instead of

```
try{
autio.play()
}
catch{
console.log("error playing")
}
```